# IPhone SDK calloutview replacement

Tags: iphone, ios, annotations

i came across a code at this site: http://www.eidac.de/?p=183 that give the same function as the annotation in the MapKit, it works great when the label text of the annotation is short. However, when the text is long, the Uibutton is unclickabla, does anyone use the code an have the solution? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The layoutSubviews portion of CallOutView.m has bugs in it that make the CalloutView's frame too small (touch events don't get passed to the button because the button is outside of the view's bounds). While I think the function needs to be rewritten altogether, the easiest way to fix the problem is to delete the `self.frame = frame;` on line 186 and add the following to the end of the function.

```
frame.size.width = calloutLeft.frame.size.width + 
        calloutCenter.frame.size.width + calloutRight.frame.size.width + 
        calloutButton.frame.size.width + MIN_RIGHT_IMAGE_WIDTH;
self.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution to be my favourite.

It lets you extend it and put images in there too!

http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/